# Kafka RangeAssignor benefits over RoundRobin

Tags: apache-kafka

RangeAssignor is the default partition assignment strategy in Kafka.
Although comparing to RoundRobin, RangeAssignor does not assign partitions evenly.

Why is it chosen to be default partition assignment strategy? What benefits does it have over RoundRobin?

Comment: This guy explains pretty clearly https://medium.com/streamthoughts/understanding-kafka-partition-assignment-strategies-and-how-to-write-your-own-custom-assignor-ebeda1fc06f3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is useful, for example, to join records from two topics which have the same number of partitions and the same key-partitioning logic